# How to handle inconventient timing of intelligence test/personality test?

Tags: interviewing, germany, travel

A company I'm applying to wants me to take an online intelligence/personality test before the second interview (I've already had a phone interview) and then discuss the results when I'm on site. I presume that a negative test outcome would mean that my chances of getting the job are reduced.

Ordinarily, this would be fine, however, performing the on site interview at all will require me to travel a whole day each direction from my current location to the companies premises and back, which is further complicated by pandemic restrictions. Thus I feel like I might waste a huge amount of time if I turn up at the interview just to be turned down due to some perceived lack of fit that could also be cleared up ahead of time. What can I do in this situation? The interviewer has made it clear that they want me to show up regardless of how I perform on the test and I'm afraid that asking them to consider a second remote interview before the on site will reflect negatively on me.

Comment: Take the test, and than ask frankly (via mail or phone) do you have a chance for a job. Mention same things you mentioned here (travel cost, loss of time, restrictions) . Reasonable company would understand. Unreasonable company - well, do you really want to work for them ?

Comment: @rs.29 That's a good point, everything else has seemed to go very well so far so I was wary of upsetting someone but they probably would see how this is difficult for me.

Comment: You can ask for travel reimbursement. If they haven't written on their job advertisement they won't reimburse, they are actually obliged by law to do it. But I would just ask nicely and not expect it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not performing well on an intelligence/personality test isn't a barrier to being recruited.  There's many people who absolutely hate doing these tests and feel a lot of anxiety about them.  I don't like them, I don't think I perform well at them.

Your interviewer seems confident enough in you (as a person) to want to see you regardless of the test results - I would certainly take that as a positive.

So do the test to the best of your ability and take note of what sections you felt that you struggled with.  Before the interview, think about those sections and how you feel you could improve or expand on.

Think of the test as being a foundation for discussion points in part of the interview.  It's entirely possible that your interviewer isn't really interested in the test results (they're just part of the formal process) and wants to talk to you as a person (as opposed to a set of test results).

Comment: Note that personality tests usually contain lots of pointless questions that will be completely ignored. Like "What is your favourite colour" - nobody cares what your favourite colour is (I hope), the question is just there so you don't figure out which are the really relevant questions.

Answer (score 0):

As @rs.29 said in the comments, you should bring this up with your recruiter.  Let them know that you would be happy to take the test online, but if the test comes back negative, then you would prefer to simply end the recruiting process at that time and not proceed to the onsite interview, to save your time and frustration of having to take an entire day to just go to a decline meeting.  The company will either understand that you don't want to waste your time commuting to a meeting where nothing will be accomplished, or  they won't.  In the former case, great, in the latter case, this company just wants to string you  along  and waste your time so they're probably not worth it anyway.